# What is the theoretical explanation of D/F# chord in this turnaround?

Tags: harmony, analysis

Here is the sequence in harmonic Am. What is the function of D/F# in terms of tonal harmony. Borrowed chord from parallel major? Chromatic inflection?

Am-D/F#-F-E-A

Comment: It doesn't matter. There is no "theoretical explanation" There is a functional explanation which is ultimately whatever you you can come with that "makes sense" and ideally is as simple as possible. Clearly in harmonic minor the iv chord is a IV chord and this is just an inversion to create a smooth chromatic bassline. In music theory, theory doesn't come before music it comes after. Don't confuse the map with the territory as it will get you nowhere.

Comment: @Gupta it certainly doesn't matter _in some contexts,_ but that doesn't mean that we should abandon attempts to create theoretical frameworks to explain music.  While it's true that a lot of theory is developed descriptively, that doesn't stop it from being used prescriptively by subsequent composers -- who then innovate to the point that the theory needs to be changed in order to describe their music.  But still, composers do typically write music with a preconceived set of theoretical rules describing what "makes sense."

Comment: Is the last chord A or Am?

Comment: @phoog What makes "sense" is relative. In an insane asylum such as the US government what makes sense is entirely different, than, say a farmer who has to grow his own food to survive. Sure there is some common underlying "logic" but it is very small relatively to most of the artificial rules created by men. For example, much of music pre-cpp was founded on religious "theory" such as 3 and 7 is the perfect number. This then shaped everything to come afterwards but really had nothing to do with actual foundations of music.

Comment: @phoog "Theory" is only used to give us a walking cane because we are blind. It helps guide us imbeciles in to being able to accomplish something. The more "gifted" we are the less theory we need. There are some great musicians who know no formal theory.  Theory as we know it, formal theory, is just for communication. Music theory is not a theory in the sense of a mathematical theory except for nomenclature(naming chords and the taxonomic topological structure of "music theory" is relevant). 95% of the "rules" of theory is BS.

Comment: @phoog What modern "music theory" gives us when it describes functional progressions, for example, is not a theory but a documentation of what certain cultures and masters did. It doesn't tell you what should be done unless you want to sound like them. I'm not saying theory is bad but one must always temper it's conclusions so one doesn't fall into the myopic trap of thinking theory = reality.

Comment: @phoog for example, many of the rules for counterpoint, while some based entirely on logical reasons, produce a certain sound. If you follow those rules you will get that sound. If you want a new sound you must change the rules. Much of contemporary music has to break the rules("theory") to have created a new sound. E.g., take Jazz... If Jazz used the classical rules it would not be Jazz.  The point here is that music theory should not be taken as some absolute rule-set that one cannot break. In fact, learning theory should come after learning music.

Comment: @Gupta other than the role of 3 in mensuration theory, I don't see much evidence for a preference for 3 or 7 driving music theory.  It's more that they got excited when the number 3 or 7 turned up than that they did things based on those numbers.  Do you have any evidence to the contrary?  I'd be interested to see it.  "There are some great musicians who know no formal theory": not from the common practice period!  "theory should not be taken as some absolute rule-set that one cannot break": absolutely.  But it's also a useful tool for people learning to compose, if not an indispensable one.

Comment: @phoog Surely you realize the important of 3 in 7 in the Christian religion? No doubt then it would shape Christian music. Music is far more cultural than mathematical. "Meter in Music" by Houle goes rather deeply in to the discussion of ternary meter as do several other books. I believe Kent Kennan's Counterpoint book also discusses it. Most books that discuss historical music usually at least touch on this aspect. Most (western) pre-cpp music was written in ternary as most music.  "A History Of Musical Style" by Crocker also discusses it in depth.

Comment: @phoog As far as what musicians new about theory in cpp isn't debatable since there is no way to prove either side. Clearly though the best musicians are the only ones remembered and generally have any historical record. Also, modern theory is based on the *COMMON PRACTICE* of those musicians and was not a theory at the time. The theory as we know it is much different than what they new(although some of it hasn't changed at all).  Given that many cultures form their own musical sense and their "theories" are different suggest that theory is not as relevant as you seem to think.

Comment: @phoog What is more important is to immerse oneself in music to develop a coherent personal understanding of how music works. The greats all did this or they wouldn't be great. There are many musicians today who are known to not have any understanding of "music theory" but create good music. I'm sure the same was true back in CPP. Of course not knowing theory might limit their abilities but theory can also hinder people who think they have to create music "by the numbers".

Answer (score 4):

It's just a predominant (IV) chord borrowed from A major. It serves the same harmonic function as the F (bVI) chord that follows, but allows for the creation of a chromatic bass line F#-F-E leading to the dominant (E) chord.

Comment: Does Dekkadeci's answer negate this one?

Comment: @Tim No. It's a difference in how theorists consider the basis of the major IV chord in minor. But regardless which point of view one adheres to, it's still a predominant function chord, and it still participates in a chromatic descending bass line. The debate over the theoretical basis of the major-IV's origin doesn't impact it's function within the chord progression.

Answer (score 4):

The D/F♯ chord is a IV6 chord in A minor.

While the IV chord in a minor key does often end up sounding borrowed in practice, my Royal Conservatory of Music Harmony lessons all said that **IV in a minor key does not count as borrowing from the tonic major, as IV is already a fully acceptable chord in minor keys**.

Comment: Due, I guess, to the existence of the melodic minor scale.

Comment: @Tim I'd say it's the other way around: the melodic minor scale exists because composers routinely used the major IV chord (i.e., raised scale degree 6) in minor.

Comment: @Aaron - or - were they thinking more in Dorian mode..?

Comment: @Tim I don't know the history well enough, but it certainly seems plausible that the raised sixth in minor was a holdover from dorian.

Comment: I have to say, the "fully acceptable" argument doesn't convince me.  Is V is a first-class citizen in minor or borrowed from the parallel major?  What about V/V?  Or should that be V/v?  Is any chord somehow not "fully acceptable" in any key?  What criteria do they use to decide which are or aren't?

Comment: @phoog - My RCM lessons said that V is a first-class citizen in minor keys, while V/V is not. Only cases like the Neapolitan (bII) were shaky.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I figured as much, but why?  Is it because they consider that there are 9 "acceptable" pitch classes in a minor key (namely seven diatonic to the natural minor plus raised ^6 and ^7)?  I just don't find that convincing as a useful distinction.  But then again I never found the concept of "borrowing" to be particularly helpful.